# Swift error "Cannot invoke 'makeNoise' with an argument type '((UInt32))'"

Tags: swift

I have been doing some Swift coding and I got "Cannot invoke 'makeNoise' with an argument type '((UInt32))'". Here is the full code:

```
 func makePetMakeNoise(){
        var randomNumber = arc4random_uniform(9) 
       self.pet.makeNoise(randomNumber)
```

I am using `arc4random_uniform(9)` to make A random number between 1 and 9. How would I fix the error?

Comment: show makeNoise definition

Comment: Ok here it is: func makeNoise() -> Int{  
     
        if Bool(canMakeNoise) == true{
            println("\(name) \(noise)")
        }else if Bool(canMakeNoise) == false{
            println("\(name) *remains silent*")
        }
        
    }

Comment: Well your function doesn't take a parameter so trying to pass one will cause an error.

Comment: so makeNoise method accepts no arguments. of course you can't invoke it

Answer (score 0):

Your method call returns an Int, it doesn't accept one. Although, you never actually return from it. Based on what you have here, your call should be:

```
self.pet.makeNoise()
```

and the method declaration should be:

```
func makeNoise() 
{
    //Your if statement that prints stuff.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`arc4random_uniform(UInt32)` takes a `UInt32` as an argument and returns a `UInt32` which is not the same as your function takes. And according to the function you provided, it does not take a parameter so it does not work. Make the function take an `Int`(and adjust accordingly) or a `UInt32` as a parameter then use the parameter. I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do with `Bool(canMakeNoise)`, but I think you're trying to check the random number against a given value?

function:

```
func makeNoise(x: Int) { 
    if x == 0 { // Or some value the pet can make
        println("(name) (noise)") 
    } else { 
        println("(name) remains silent") 
    }
}
```

call:

```
let x = Int(arc4random_uniform(5)) // This is now an Int not a UInt32
makeNoise(x)
```

Comment: Thanks Ian, Is there someway to put that stuff into a init method? Code:init(name:String,noise:String,canMakeNoise:Bool){
        self.name = name
        self.noise = noise
        self.canMakeNoise = canMakeNoise
    }